# removing some part of a text file in python

Tags: python

I have a very big text file and I want to filter out some lines. the first line is Identifier and it is followed by many lines (numbers in different lines) like this example:

example:

```
fixedStep ch=GL000219.1 start=52818 step=1
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
fixedStep ch=GL000320.1 start=52959 step=1
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
fixedStep ch=M start=52959 step=1
1.000000
1.000000
```

this line is identifier: `fixedStep ch=GL000219.1 start=52818 step=1`
I want to filter out all identifier lines containing `ch=GL000219.1` and `ch=GL000320.1` and the following lines (the numbers) and keep other identifiers and the corresponding lines (numbers) below them. each identifier is repeated multiple times.
 like this output:

```
fixedStep ch=M start=52959 step=1
1.000000
1.000000
```

I have tried this code:

```
l = ["ch=GL000219.1", "ch=GL000320.1"] # since I have more identifiers that should be removed 

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        good_data = True
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('fixedStep'):
                for i in l:
                    good_data = i not in line
            if good_data:
                outfile.write(line)
```

my code does not return what I want. do you know how to modify the code?

Comment: Add a `break` under `good_data = i not in line` if it ever becomes `False`. `good_data` can take multiple values for a single line because it's overwriting itself, so it only has to be `True` for the last value of `i`

Comment: Also, `good_data` needs to reset for every line, no?

Comment: I tried but does not make difference.

Comment: There's a few changes you need to make if I understand your question correctly. What did you try?

Comment: if I do not call the list and try the identifiers one by one it works for one of them each time perfectly but it took me lot of time to try that for all of them. I would like to do that for all identifiers at once.

Answer (score 1):

You placed this line in the wrong place:

```
good_data = True
```

Once it is set to false, it won't to be true again.

You can write like this:

```
l = ["ch=GL000219.1", "ch=GL000320.1"]
flag = False                                                                        

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:                                                                                
    for line in f:                                                                  
        if line.strip().startswith("fixedStep"):                                    
            flag = all(i not in line for i in l)                                    
        if flag:                                                                    
            outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: it removes every line below the identifiers even the ones that I am interested in

Comment: @john what do you mean by "removes every line", I didn't understand !

Comment: every identifier has some lines below (like the example). I would like to remove the some of the identifiers that I am not interested in and the following lines. indeed there are also some identifiers that I am interested in and I want them and corresponding lines that are below them. like example

Comment: @john I understand. I updated the code, is that what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to split strings(the content of the text file)into lines after you read them from a text file . using

> print(f)

after read to f, you will find that is a string not lines.

if it's a unix ending text file,using

> f = f.split("\n")

to convert string to list, then you can loop it by lines.